# SELECT ... INTO Understanding its behavior

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I was told that I could check whether a SELECT statement finds a column with the syntax

```
$rows = query( "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = idx");
if ( $rows == false )
```

and it seems to work.

Anyway, if I check `if ( $rows == 0 )` it doesn't return the same value.

Shouldn't `0` and `false` be the same (apart from the type, of course)?

What's the actual value returned by the query when it finds no row? I ask because it doesn't seems to be false, since the statement `var_dump( $rows === false )` prints `false`..

***EDIT: I'm sorry guys, query() was a function from a library someone else wrote and I had no idea (i'm starting  now with sql...). It simply excutes an SQL statement, returning an array of all rows in result set or false on (non-fatal) error (like row not found).

I have still a little question, though.
The function returns false when it finds no row, so shouldn't I be able to catch that with `if ( $rows === false )`?

Why `var_dump(false)` doens't print me out anything, while `var_dump(true)` prints me out `1`?

Comment: do you mean `mysql_query()` instead of `query()`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to close the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure if you use simple `mysql_*` functions, MySQLi or PDO but in any case `$rows` is not returning the number of resulting rows. It is a boolean value / object returned / created depending of success of your query.

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id='1'");
if(!$sql->error)
  $number_of_rows = $sql->num_rows; // for sure it will output 1
```